# array_rand will not work inside a conditional statement

Tags: php, arrays, random, conditional-statements

I'm working inside a foreach loop, and trying to put my array_rand inside an if statement. It *will not work* inside the if statement, but if I take it out of the if statement (as is) it works. And, by the way, this is true inside and outside of the foreach loop. It will not work inside the if statement regardless of whether I place it before or after the loop. But it will work before or after the loop if I take it out of the if statement.

```
foreach($files as $file) {
$randcolor = array("red","green","blue","yellow","brown","black","orange","white","silver","purple","pink");
    if(isset($color)) {
        $color = $color;
    }
    else {
        $color = $randcolor[array_rand($randcolor)];
    }

    ... bunch of other stuff

}
```

I've tried spelling out each of the colors in their own     `if($color === 'red'){etc.}`    statements. I've tried    `if(!$color){$color = $randcolor[array_rand($randcolor)];}`    Nothing works. It will not work inside an if statement. If I take it out, it works, but then I can't define specific colors with the $color attribute anymore. Strangely, even if I define specific colors *after* an unconditional array_rand statement, it still takes over and overrides any other color specs.

**EDIT** Forget to mention that by "will not work" I mean, it doesn't output any string at all. Just blank.

**UPDATE**

For clarity: $color is an attribute in the shortcode, so it gets defined by the shortcode itself.

**UPDATE 2**

I output this at the end of a long shortcode, with a `return $thefiles` where `$thefiles` = a long html string, which includes $color in a div class.

** UPDATE 3 **
More of the code:

```
foreach($files as $file) {
        $randcolor = array("red","green","blue","yellow","brown","black","orange","white","silver","purple","pink");
        if(!($color)){$color = $randcolor[array_rand($randcolor)];}


        $thefiles .= '<a id="sssf" style="width:'.$width.$perpx.'" class="'.$style.$corners.'" href="'.$link.'" download><div class="sssf-filetype sssf-'.$color.'"><div class="sssf-label">'.$ftype.'</div></div>'.$cleanName.' <span style="float:right;">'.$fsize.'</span></a>';

    unset($color);
        }

    }

return $thefiles;
```

}

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the issue you're talking about. Could you update the question with a specific test-case that fails?

Comment: Serious question: what more do you need? (Not sarcasm.) This is the actual code.

Comment: what is `$color` variable defined as?

Comment: Sorry, it's an attribute in a shortcode.

Comment: simply do this  `if(!($color)) {   $color = $randcolor[array_rand($randcolor)];  }`

Comment: @Thom: I don't see you outputting the string anywhere. This code [works for me](https://eval.in/54147).

Comment: I output the string at the end of a mega-long shortcode. 

return $thefiles;

where $thefiles is defined as an html string.

Comment: @user2092317 - That SORT OF worked. The problem is, weirdly, it's now only picking one color foreach $file, like it would if it were outside the loop. But I need it to pick different a random color for each file. But it's progress, because at least it's outputting something again.

Comment: @Thom: I can't see the full function, so I don't know what else you're doing with the `$color` variable. Anyway, to troubleshoot, you can try `var_dump($color);` at various places in the script and see how the value changes.

Comment: Unless you're unsetting it somewhere, then $color will be defined every iteration except the first, so it won't go into the else clause: you need to `unset($color)` at the end of each iteration of the loop

Comment: @Mark Baker, how do I do that? That sounds promising.

Comment: @Mark Baker, I've tried unsetting $color `unset($color);` in several places after the output string is defined and before the return, but if I do that, then it unsets the color if it's defined as, say, red, for all files in the loop. So that doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: If it's unsetting it for all files in the loop, then you've got a by-reference somewhere, so you really need to show a bit more of what you're doing

Comment: Happy to, don't know what a by-reference is though. Will update with some more right now.

Comment: I've updated it with much of the shortcode. It looks a mess at the moment, but I'll clean it up. Just wanted to get it up there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
$randcolor = array("red","green","blue","yellow","brown","black","orange","white","silver","purple","pink");
$useColor = $color;
if(!($color)){
    $useColor = $randcolor[array_rand($randcolor)];
}

$thefiles .= '<a id="sssf" style="width:'.$width.$perpx.'" class="'.$style.$corners.'" href="'.$link.'" download><div class="sssf-filetype sssf-'.$useColor.'"><div class="sssf-label">'.$ftype.'</div></div>'.$cleanName.' <span style="float:right;">'.$fsize.'</span></a>';
```

But define $randcolor **outside** the foreach() loop: as it doesn't change, you don't need to redefine it for every single file

Comment: Thanks, Mark. Trying that now.

Comment: Thank you, Mark! You nailed it. I had tried something similar to that, except I did it backwards. I had tried `$color = $dummycolor`. This did the trick. Appreciate your patient help.

Comment: For posterity, Mark's answer works *without* unsetting $color.

Answer (score 1):

`isset` is used to check if the variable is `NULL` or not. In your case, `$color` is having the value `NULL` because of which your if condition is not getting executed. If you  put `$color = ''` or define your attribute `$color` your code should work.

i have tried and it works for me: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/kwx-511

Comment: I only starting using isset after several other attempts. I'll take a look. Thanks!